# Creating a scrollable matrix in html with tables

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I want to have something like a matrix in a html page. The content of the table/matrix should be scrollable but the row and column titles should be fixed so they are always visible.

I tried to do that with having 3 tables: one for the column-titles, one for the row-titles and one for the content itself. It looks fine when all the content fits on the page. However, as soon as there is not enough space to fit all the content, the whole thing gets messed up. How can I prevent this from happening and make the tables always appear on one line and add a scrollbar if necessary instead of moving the content table to the next line?

[image: messed up matrix]
[image: matrix]

This is my html:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="tableparent">
                <table class = "table rowtitle table-striped">
                    <tr><td>Logo</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>1</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>2</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>3</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>4</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>5</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>6</td></tr>
                </table>


                <table class="table columntitle table-striped">

                    <tr>
                        <th>1</th>
                        <th>2</th>
                        <th>3</th>
                        <th>4</th>
                        <th>5</th>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table class="table table-striped">

                    <tr>
                        <td>X</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>X</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>


                    <tr>
                        <td>X</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>X</td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>X</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>X</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>                       
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>X</td>
                        <td>X</td>
                        <td>X</td>
                        <td>X</td>
                    </tr>                       
                    <tr>
                        <td>X</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>X</td>
                        <td>X</td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>X</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>X</td>
                    </tr>


                </table>


    </div>
```

And this is the relevant part of the CSS:

```
    table {
      max-width: 100%;
      background-color: transparent;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      border-spacing: 0;
    }

    .table {
      white-space: nowrap;
    }

    .table th,
    .table td {
      padding: 8px;
      line-height: 20px;
      text-align: center;
      vertical-align: top;
      border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    }

    .table th {
      font-weight: bold;
    }

.table-striped tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > td,
.table-striped tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > th {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

.rowtitle {
    float: left;
    padding: 8px;
    border-right: 0px;
    height: 200px;
}

.rowtitle th, 
.rowtitle td {
    border-right: 0px;
}

.columntitle {
    padding: 8px;
    border-bottom: 0px;
}

.columntitle th, 
.columntitle td {
    border-bottom: 0px;
}

.tableparent {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Just wondering - why don't you put everything in 1 table?

Comment: Check out datatables.net.  That might have the functionailty you're looking for without reinventing the wheel.  I think you'll keep on finding uses that will break if you go it alone.

Comment: I can't put it in one table, because I want the rows and the columns to be scrollable and the row or column titles have to scroll with the content but also need to be visible all the time. So if I would scroll horizontally to the row "4" the row titles should remain visible/fixed at the left side while the columns 1, 2 and 3 are scrolled away and are no longer visible to the user. I need that because there can be a lot of entries like 100 in both directions.

Comment: Was your issue finally resolved?

Answer (score 1):

[This works  in all modern browsers that I tried](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/Jg5vr/1/). I had to mess around with several things for a while, but the result seems to be what you wanted. The trick was to put `position:absolute` for top row and the content section. I changed your html slightly as well

**HTML** (changed slightly):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="tableparent">
            <table class = "table rowtitle">
                <tr><td>Logo</td></tr>
                <tr><td>1</td></tr>
                <tr><td>2</td></tr>
                <tr><td>3</td></tr>
                <tr><td>4</td></tr>
                <tr><td>5</td></tr>
                <tr><td>6</td></tr>
            </table>


            <table class="table columntitle">

                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>1</th>
                    <th>2</th>
                    <th>3</th>
                    <th>4</th>
                    <th>5</th>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table class="table content table-striped">

                <tr>
                    <td>X</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>X</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>X</td>
                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <td>X</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>X</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>X</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>X</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>X</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>                       
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>X</td>
                    <td>X</td>
                    <td>X</td>
                    <td>X</td>
                    <td>X</td>
                </tr>                       
                <tr>
                    <td>X</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>X</td>
                    <td>X</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>X</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>X</td>
                    <td>X</td>
                </tr>


            </table>


</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
table {      
      border-collapse:collapse;
      table-layout:fixed;
    }
table * {
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    min-width:50px;
    min-height:50px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

.rowtitle {
    float:left;
    opacity:1;
    z-index:3;
}

    .table th,
    .table td {
      text-align: center;
      border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    }

    .table th {
      font-weight: bold;
    }

.table-striped tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > td,
.table-striped tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > th {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

.columntitle {
    z-index:1;
    position:fixed;
}

.content {
    position:fixed;
    left:60px;
    top:59px;
    width:255px;
    overflow-x:auto;
    display: block;
}
```